# Can't install nuget package provider in powershell core 6.2.0

Tags: azure, powershell, nuget

I have webjob in azure. I try to install Az module to powershell core 6.2.0 using the following code:

```
using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
{
    ps.Runspace = runspace;
    ps.AddScript("Install-Module -Name Az -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser - 
    Force;");
}
```

But in azure webjob console log I get an error about installing nuget package provider. Then I try to install NuGet package provider using the followeing command:

```
ps.AddScript("Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion '2.8.5.201' -Force;");
```

But I get the following error:

> [04/10/2019 15:54:00 > 674fe9: ERR ] Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Unhandled Exception - Message:'The type initializer for 'Microsoft.PackageManagement.Internal.Utility.Plugin.DynamicType' threw an exception.' Name:'TypeInitializationException' Stack Trace:'   at Microsoft.PackageManagement.Internal.Utility.Plugin.DynamicType.Create(Type tInterface, OrderedDictionary`2 instanceMethods, List`2 delegateMethods, List`1 stubMethods, List`2 usedInstances)
>   [04/10/2019 15:54:00 > 674fe9: ERR ]    at Microsoft.PackageManagement.Internal.Utility.Plugin.DynamicInterface.CreateProxy(Type tInterface, Object[] instances)
>   [04/10/2019 15:54:00 > 674fe9: ERR ]    at Microsoft.PackageManagement.Internal.Utility.Plugin.DynamicInterface.DynamicCast(Type tInterface, Object[] instances)
>   [04/10/2019 15:54:00 > 674fe9: ERR ]    at Microsoft.PackageManagement.Internal.Utility.Plugin.DynamicInterface.DynamicCast[TInterface](Object[] instances)
>   [04/10/2019 15:54:00 > 674fe9: ERR ]    at Microsoft.PackageManagement.Internal.Utility.Plugin.DynamicInterfaceExtensions.As[TInterface](Object instance)
>   [04/10/2019 15:54:00 > 674fe9: ERR ]    at Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.CmdletBase.get_PackageManagementHost()
>   [04/10/2019 15:54:00 > 674fe9: ERR ]    at Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.CmdletBase.SelectProviders(String[] names)
>   [04/10/2019 15:54:00 > 674fe9: ERR ]    at Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.CmdletWithProvider.get_SelectedProviders()
>   [04/10/2019 15:54:00 > 674fe9: ERR ]    at Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackageProvider.get_SelectedProviders()
>   [04/10/2019 15:54:00 > 674fe9: ERR ]    at Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.CmdletWithProvider.b__23_0()
>   [04/10/2019 15:54:00 > 674fe9: ERR ]    at Microsoft.PackageManagement.Internal.Utility.Extensions.DictionaryExtensions.GetOrAdd[TKey,TValue](IDictionary`2 dictionary, TKey key, Func`1 valueFunction)
>   [04/10/2019 15:54:00 > 674fe9: ERR ]    at Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.CmdletWithProvider.get_CachedSelectedProviders()
>   [04/10/2019 15:54:00 > 674fe9: ERR ]    at Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.CmdletWithProvider.GenerateDynamicParameters()
>   [04/10/2019 15:54:00 > 674fe9: ERR ]    at Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.AsyncCmdlet.<>c__DisplayClass83_0.b__0()') ---> System.Exception: Unhandled Exception - Message:'The type initializer for 'Microsoft.PackageManagement.Internal.Utility.Plugin.DynamicType' threw an exception.' Name:'TypeInitializationException' Stack Trace:'   at Microsoft.PackageManagement.Internal.Utility.Plugin.DynamicType.Create(Type tInterface, OrderedDictionary`2 instanceMethods, List`2 delegateMethods, List`1 stubMethods, List`2 usedInstances)
>   [04/10/2019 15:54:00 > 674fe9: ERR ]    at Microsoft.PackageManagement.Internal.Utility.Plugin.DynamicInterface.CreateProxy(Type tInterface, Object[] instances)
>   [04/10/2019 15:54:00 > 674fe9: ERR ]    at Microsoft.PackageManagement.Internal.Utility.Plugin.DynamicInterface.DynamicCast(Type tInterface, Object[] instances)
>   [04/10/2019 15:54:00 > 674fe9: ERR ]    at Microsoft.PackageManagement.Internal.Utility.Plugin.DynamicInterface.DynamicCast[TInterface](Object[] instances)
>   [04/10/2019 15:54:00 > 674fe9: ERR ]    at Microsoft.PackageManagement.Internal.Utility.Plugin.DynamicInterfaceExtensions.As[TInterface](Object instance)
>   [04/10/2019 15:54:00 > 674fe9: ERR ]    at Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.CmdletBase.get_PackageManagementHost()
>   [04/10/2019 15:54:00 > 674fe9: ERR ]    at Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.CmdletBase.SelectProviders(String[] names)
>   [04/10/2019 15:54:00 > 674fe9: ERR ]    at Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.CmdletWithProvider.get_SelectedProviders()
>   [04/10/2019 15:54:00 > 674fe9: ERR ]    at Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackageProvider.get_SelectedProviders()
>   [04/10/2019 15:54:00 > 674fe9: ERR ]    at Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.CmdletWithProvider.b__23_0()
>   [04/10/2019 15:54:00 > 674fe9: ERR ]    at Microsoft.PackageManagement.Internal.Utility.Extensions.DictionaryExtensions.GetOrAdd[TKey,TValue](IDictionary`2 dictionary, TKey key, Func`1 valueFunction)
>   [04/10/2019 15:54:00 > 674fe9: ERR ]    at Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.CmdletWithProvider.get_CachedSelectedProviders()
>   [04/10/2019 15:54:00 > 674fe9: ERR ]    at Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.CmdletWithProvider.GenerateDynamicParameters()
>   [04/10/2019 15:54:00 > 674fe9: ERR ]    at Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.AsyncCmdlet.<>c__DisplayClass83_0.b__0()'

What is wrong with it? How to install package provider to powershell core? 
Or how to install Az module without nuget?
Help, please)

Answer (score 0):

This might also seem to work. 
Have you tried this option?

```
Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force
```

You can also take a look at the below article just for the reference.

[Install Package Provider with Powershell 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/packagemanagement/install-packageprovider?view=powershell-6)